# Mapbox Geocoder without Map

Tags: mapbox, geocoding, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

How can I use Mapbox Geocoder without map?

When I remove the map code, the autocomplete text field disappears.

What I have tried is (Which is not working for me):

```
    <div id="geocoder"></div>

    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiaGFzc2Fuc2FyZGFyYmFuZ2FzaCIsImEiOiJjazg3MHNldWowbGllM2hvMGloMGY0MXd0In0.baO5lzQ8q4al4T0rDAloQA';

    var geocoder = new MapboxGeocoder({
        accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,
        mapboxgl: mapboxgl
    });

    geocoder.on('select', function (data) {

        geocoder._toggle()
    })

    geocoder.on('result', function(result) {
       console.log(result);
    })

    document.getElementById('geocoder');
```

How can I manage to use only Geocoder autocomplete, with out showing map?

Here is my working fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/rv085oL1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for `mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder` [here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder/blob/master/API.md#addto) explains how to add a geocoder without a map. That is, the JavaScript in your JSFiddle should be updated to:

```
var geocoder = new MapboxGeocoder({ accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken });
geocoder.addTo('#geocoder');
```

Also, you'll need to update your `mapbox-gl-geocoder` version to at least `v4.5.0`. This is the version in which the `addTo` method was integrated, as noted in the changelog [here](http://l).

Comment: Yeah I just upgraded my mapbox-gl-geocoder version to v4.5.0, and used geocoder.addTo('#geocoder');. It worked like a charm. Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: Hi,@Adriana, could you tell me how to get the user selected text value from a list? in this case I tried with this code `document.querySelector('[aria-label="Search"]');` but I couldn't. Otherwise, Is there any way to get the value?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a **react** **implementation** of a geocoder **without** a **map**:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-geocoder-mapbox

It does not look pretty, but you can style it with CSS :)

In the project directory:

`npm i --save react-geocoder-mapbox`

Inside of the component you want the geocoder:

`import Geocoder from "react-geocoder-mapbox";`

Include the component in your app:

```
export const GeocoderWithoutMap = () => {
const [geocode, setGeocode] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
console.log(geocode);
}, [geocode]);

return (
 <Geocoder
   accessToken={TOKEN}
   onSelect={geocoderObject => { setGeocode(geocoderObject);}}
  />
 );
};
```

I hope this saves you the time I spent searching!